# Can't access two React apps behind nginx reverse proxy by uri

Tags: reactjs, nginx, https

I have two React apps, running on ports 3001 and 3002. They both do their own authentication, so I'm using auth0, which apparently requires that the app run under HTTPS. (which makes sense.) So in my browser, https://localhost:3001 and https://localhost:3002 both successfully launch the desired React app.

I want 3001 to respond to 'https://localhost/', and 3002 to respond to 'https://localhost/admin'. But when I go to "https://localhost/admin" in my browser, I'm expecting it to launch 3002, but instead it launches 3001.

My nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    ssl_certificate /home/william/crm/devCerts/localhost.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/william/crm/devCerts/localhost-key.pem;

    location /admin/ {
#       rewrite ^/admin(.*) $1 break;
        proxy_pass "https://localhost:3002/";
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:3001/;
    }
}
```

Uncommenting out the rewrite statement doesn't help.